# Clear row with list of inline elements, pseudo has no effect in Safari

Tags: css, list, less, inline, line-breaks

I've created a list with inline elements in order to position them centered horizontally over multiple lines. While the below code works in Chrome and Firefox, the pseudo attribute does not take effect in Safari. Is there a workaround for this or do I need a different approach? (Note: LESS formatted)

```
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    li {
        display: inline;
        &:nth-child(4):after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Found a solution -

```
&:nth-child(4):after {
     content: '\a';
     display: block;
     white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't work in IE at all. You could use JS for this.

Comment: nth-child is supported in IE9, which is my only requirement for IE in this case.

Comment: If you're answering your own question, use the answer form below.  Otherwise, this looks like an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0):

```
&:nth-child(4):after {
     content: '\a';
     display: block;
     white-space: pre;
}
```